# Ao tentar obter o id do usuário salvo no sharedPreferences, as vezes o mesmo retorna nulo

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, sharedpreferences

Ao fazer login no aplicativo, eu salvo seus dados no SharedPreferences utilizando GSON (para salvar a resposta da API com id, nome, email, etc).

O problema é que ao iniciar o app, eu verifico se o Model User é nulo. Se não for, ele abre a tela de busca e a partir daí eu uso User.getId() em diversas partes do aplicativo.

Porém, ao colocar o aplicativo em produção, recebi alguns crashs:

```
> EXCEPTION java.lang.NullPointerException LOCATION VagasCalls.java line
> 180 in VagasCalls.getRecommendationIds() TIME Today, 4:35 MESSAGE
> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int
> br.com.apps.jaya.vagas.Models.User.getId()' on a null object reference
```

Acredito que o usuário existe (já que entrou na tela de busca e não na de login), porém por algum motivo o Id está nulo. Não tenho certeza e gostaria de ajuda para descobrir o problema.

Obs.: Isso só está acontecendo com algumas pessoas.

**Salvando o usuário**

```
public static void saveUser(User user) {

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(user);

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(Constants.USER_INFO, json);
    editor.apply();
}
```

**Obtendo o usuário**

```
public static User getUser() {

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = sharedPreferences.getString(Constants.USER_INFO, "");
    return gson.fromJson(json, User.class);
}
```

**Model - User**

```
public class User implements Parcelable {

    @Expose
    @SerializedName("id")
    private int id;

    @SerializedName("identidade")
    @Expose
    private String identity;

    @SerializedName("nome")
    @Expose
    private String name;

    @SerializedName("foto")
    @Expose
    private String picture;

    @SerializedName("genero")
    @Expose
    private String genre;

    @Expose
    private String email;

    protected User(Parcel in) {
        id = in.readInt();
        identity = in.readString();
        name = in.readString();
        picture = in.readString();
        genre = in.readString();
        email = in.readString();
    }

    public static final Creator<User> CREATOR = new Creator<User>() {
        @Override
        public User createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new User(in);
        }

        @Override
        public User[] newArray(int size) {
            return new User[size];
        }
    };

    public String getPicture() {
        return picture;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getIdentity() {
        return identity;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeInt(id);
        dest.writeString(identity);
        dest.writeString(name);
        dest.writeString(picture);
        dest.writeString(genre);
        dest.writeString(email);
    }
}
```

**Crash**

```
> br.com.apps.jaya.vagas.VagasAPI   VagasCalls.java line 180 in
> VagasCalls.getRecommendationIds()
> br.com.apps.jaya.vagas.Helpers    NotificationsHelper.java line 143 in
> NotificationsHelper.getRecommendationIdsForUser()
> br.com.apps.jaya.vagas.Fragments  SearchFragment.java line 263 in
> SearchFragment.updateNotificationsIcon()
> br.com.apps.jaya.vagas.Fragments  SearchFragment.java line 179 in
> SearchFragment.onResume() android.app Fragment.java line 2096 in
> Fragment.performResume() android.app  FragmentManager.java line 928 in
> FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState() android.app FragmentManager.java
> line 1067 in FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState()
> android.app   FragmentManager.java line 1049 in
> FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState() android.app FragmentManager.java
> line 1879 in FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchResume()
> android.app   Activity.java line 6089 in Activity.performResume()
> android.app   ActivityThread.java line 3145 in
> ActivityThread.performResumeActivity() android.app    ActivityThread.java
> line 3187 in ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity()
> android.app   ActivityThread.java line 1411 in
> ActivityThread$H.handleMessage() android.os   Handler.java line 102 in
> Handler.dispatchMessage() android.os  Looper.java line 135 in
> Looper.loop() android.app ActivityThread.java line 5608 in
> ActivityThread.main() java.lang.reflect   Method.java line -2 in
> Method.invoke() java.lang.reflect Method.java line 372 in
> Method.invoke() com.android.internal.os   ZygoteInit.java line 1397 in
> ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run()
> com.android.internal.os   ZygoteInit.java line 1192 in ZygoteInit.main()
```

Eu nunca consegui reproduzir este problema. Estou utilizando o New Relic.

Comment: Em que momento da aplicação você chama o SaveUser?

Comment: Quando faço o login ou cadastro. Eu chamo o método saveUser passando a resposta da API - AccountManager.saveUser(response.body());

Comment: Você desinstalou completamente o app antes de instalar o arquivo de produção? Talvez salvou as preferências como `dev` e acabou usando para `pro`.

Comment: Então, quando me disse momento. Eu quis dizer: será que a aplicação esta tendo tempo para isso, será que ela não esta fechando, mudando de tela ou coisa assim. Entendeu?  Nunca salva, ou a vezes, funciona?

Comment: Na maioria das vezes funciona, só aconteceu com algumas pessoas. Existe a possibilidade do usuário não ser nulo mas falhar nos parâmetros? Se sim, como que eu trato?

Comment: @CleidimarViana sim =/

Comment: @ReginaldoRigo pra saber se o usuário está logado, eu verifico se o user é nulo, mas n verifico se o id ta nulo. Será que na hora de salvar ele salva o gson no shared preferences mas por algum motivo falhou em salvar os parâmetros?

Comment: Você verificou se está acontecendo para Android 6.0, pois pode ter alguma coisa a ver com permissão tbm, já que está acontecendo para algumas pessoas.

Comment: @CleidimarViana sim, verifiquei. Está acontecendo nas seguintes versões: 4.4.2, 5.0.2, 6.0, 4.4.4

Comment: Para essas condições que falha experimente ler logo após ter pedido para salvar só para ver o que acontece.

Comment: @ReginaldoRigo vou tentar!! Obrigada.

Comment: @user2391117 Dê uma olhada nessa pergunta: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786172/android-getdefaultsharedpreferences